# What is a common/practical use of Popen.wait()

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to understand this line of Code:

```
def delete_dir(dir):
    with open('/dev/null', 'w+') as null:
        subprocess.Popen("rm -r %s" % dir, shell=True, stdout=null, stderr=null).wait()
```

I'm new to programming so I lack the context to understand why this process is set to wait. What are some common practice implementation to setting a process to wait. Thanks

Comment: Note that in this particular case, you shouldn't use `subprocess` at all, you should use `shutil.rmtree(dir)`.

Comment: `wait()` will not return until the child process has exited. In this way it blocks until the status of the child process can be determined. Although I don't think this is a particularly clear in your code example, this is frequently desirable, for example, to prevent the parent and child processes from competing for the same resources in an inconsistent manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Popen.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) doesn't tell the *process* to wait, it tells *our script* to wait for the process to terminate before continuing execution. This is useful whenever the child process is doing something that will affect the behaviour of our script.

In this case, we are waiting for the `rm -r` command to finish deleting the given directory before we continue, because if our function is called `delete_dir` it is reasonable for the caller to expect the directory to be deleted before the function returns.

---

The purpose of `with open('/dev/null', 'w+') as null` (if you are curious) is to suppress any output of the child process by piping its `stdout` and `stderr` to the [`/dev/null`](https://askubuntu.com/q/12098/731225) handle.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this and then going the extra mile to explain the /dev/null "file name". I had been wondering about that. Open() deals with file objects but /dev/null is not really a file in the traditional sense so I was surprised that Open() could operate on it.

Comment: @H3G3moKnight one of the joys of Unix - [everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)